# getResourceAsStream null on stream

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I've looked around the web for quite some time without getting a answer that works.

So my issue is that I cannot load the stream of my image.
My Code as to test it:

```
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/img/AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("img/AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("conquest/img/AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/conquest/img/AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("kingconquest/conquest/img/AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/kingconquest/conquest/img/AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
System.out.println(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/eu/kingconquest/conquest/img/AQUA_KINGDOM.png"));
```

And this is my content tree:
[image: http://prntscr.com/da875i]

They all return null

Additional information:
I am using Eclipse neon(Latest stable)

I also forgot to mention that this is a plugin (exports as a "jar file")
*Plugin for minecraft spigotAPI for those interested

Comment: How is the Eclipse project "Java Build Path" configured? Source in `src`, output in `bin`? Does the `.../bin/eu/kingconquest/conquest/img` folder have a `AQUA_KINGDOM.png` file?

Comment: Not sure how to actuallly check what you just stated, I am running this as a plugin (jar file) and not a runnable jar file if that makes any diffrance.
I have not made any build path modification for the img files.

Comment: If you're running as a jar file, then your building of the jar file did not include the `.png` file. Open the jar file to confirm (it's a zip file, so any zip tool will do). Your build process is flawed.

Comment: Winrar opened the project(Is that what you meant?)
Result: conquest.jar\bin\eu\kingconquest\conquest\img
And in there lies my old images not the new :/
I have my old AQUA_CAPITAL.png in there how do I change it out?

Comment: *Ah Ha!!!* It has a `bin` in there.  As I said, it was built wrong, because the `bin` folder should not be there. `eu` should be the root folder inside `conquest.jar`. **Fix your build scripts.**

Comment: Thank you for this revalation, I sadly have no clue as to how to fix this tho.

Answer (score -2):

Try using ClassLoader like this:

```
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AQUA_KINGDOM.png");
```

Comment: [`Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/xxx/foo.bar")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) is the same as [`Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xxx/foo.bar")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), and question code has tried it all, so why do you believe adding `getClassLoader()` will make *any* difference?

Comment: When you don't use `ClassLoader` the construction of the absolute resource name is different. [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)]

Comment: Have you bothered to read the javadoc of [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), that I even linked to in my first comment? *This method delegates to this object's class loader. [...] If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.* So let me repeat: `getResourceAsStream("/xxx/foo.bar")` **is the same as** `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xxx/foo.bar‌​")`, because the first *delegates* to the second.

Comment: It says _Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:_

Comment: Exactly, and if the **starts with `/`**, it is delegated without the leading `/`, which is what I've now said for the third time.